# Flutter Web HTTP Api Call Returns 401 Error... Possibly Missing User Agent

Tags: flutter, dart, http, discord

I'm building a flutter web app that has to call to the discord api. I successfully:

```
-Get Oauth2 code
-Send code in exchange for an api token.
```

Where I run into the issue is when I call the api using that token. I know my code "works" because when I pass the same variables into Postman.com I get a proper response from the api... Specifically I know the "Authorization" and its key work. I believe my issue is with the "User-Agent". However, I don't know how to get my user agent.

I'm using http: ^0.13.5 to make the requests.

```
Future<void> getUser() async {
  var url = 'https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me';

  var client = http.Client();

  var uriResponse = await client.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': "Dart/2.19 (dart.io)",                  //Not sure if this is correct
    'Authorization': '$discAccessTokenType $discAccessToken',
  });
  Map response = json.decode(uriResponse.body);

  getUserResponse = response;
}
```

The response variable returns:

```
Response:{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}
```

Comment: Have you tried substituting in the `User-Agent` that Postman is sending, just as a test?

Comment: @ChuckBatson I just tried it to no avail. Postman passes 7 headers I believe those are what verifies its actually postman.

Comment: Ok well it would seem the `User-Agent` is not the issue then. On the bright side, if Postman can issue a successful request, then you can too. I suggest replicating Postman's request as closely as possible, including all headers, to narrow down what is the critical missing element. You might even start by working toward a successful request in `curl`.